# can open and not open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Can an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a not open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be homeomorphic ?

I guess the answer is no, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain
I found the answer on this site but I don't know how to delete this question...